# tile_get_texture() returns the whole tileset

Tags: godot

I have created a **tileset.tres** in Godot.
I have made some tiles in it, and named one of them **"orc"**.
I then use it in a script in this manner :

```
var tileset = load("tileset_test.tres")
var test_sprite = Sprite.new()

func _ready():
    var id = tileset.find_tile_by_name("orc")
    test_sprite.texture = tileset.tile_get_texture(id)
    test_sprite.position = Vector2(get_viewport_rect().size /2)
    $".".add_child(test_sprite)
```

The only problem is that it does not returns to me the specific tile "orc", but the whole tileset.
I'm confused since the documentation is pretty clear that it should give you only the texture of the tile wanted and designated by id.

Any ideas what could cause this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Issue from 11/19 [here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/33366).

Comment: Woah thanks a lot ! This is it :3